# Magento - Date of Birth Text is over the 3 Textfields

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I have an issue on the checkout form and on the fast sign up form.
I have set the Date of Birth at Order but the Text Date of Birth is overlapping the 3 fields where MM/DD/YYYY are.

How and in which folder i have to change the code to set the "Date of Birth" Text above the 3 Box Field. So i think it has to do with the css but i cant find the file to change.

I have a Theme and the Shop is only working on German Translation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can we get some code to help you with?

Comment: i can show you where the issue is.. i dont know how to find the code :-)
[link](http://www.elitshop.ch/index.php/customer/account/create/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the file you must use the browser developer tools. For example in chrome you have to right click on the element that is overlapping and than after the dev tools are open on the right you will see the css. In the top right corner it gives you the file and by clicking in the name of it for example style.css it will open a new window with a link. Follow the path in the link to find the file on your server and change it.

Comment: well i opened now the console by pressing f12 in chrome.. right i got a window and i found the field where the text is.. but how can i see which file it is ?

Comment: ok i think i found it.. ok.. and how do i have to change it now to take the position little up ?

Comment: this could be the code. 

`code`.account-create .fieldset .form-list li label {position: absolute;top:9px;left:11px;color:#777;font-family: "Cousine";font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;cursor:text;}

Comment: I cant give you an answer without seeing it. Do you have a link of your website or a screenshot ? Inspect element with right click on the element with problems would be better for you to see it.

Comment: yea, here is the link [link](http://www.elitshop.ch/index.php/customer/account/create/) i found some parts in the code but its only changing the distance of all the textes there.. i only have to set one part upper..

Comment: Log in into your cpanel hosting account than in public_html folder navigate to this path: skin/frontend/fengo/default/css/styles.css than edit the file and change the line 2869. Remove the position: absolute.

Comment: hm but now the textes are over the fields and dissapear when i write something

Comment: This was a quick fix as i see you are new here. But the best would be to style the labels of date of birth one by one using inline style on the html file to fix the bug. For that you will need to access on contact page html. Try finding it and style them with margins. And bring back the position absolute on them.

Comment: hm ok this looks like a bigger step.. i think i couldnt do that .. anyway thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Dont forget to vote up if i helped you just a little :)